# Cassandra 3.11.x downloads are missing

Tags: cassandra

We use Cassandra 3.11.13 and have found that the download for ubuntu returns a 404 when installing https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian/pool/main/c/cassandra/cassandra_3.11.13_all.deb

Added the repository for cassandra to ubuntu then
sudo apt-get install cassandra
we get a 404 on the .deb package

There are no version 3 packages in https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian/pool/main/c/cassandra/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are still using the old source for the Cassandra packages.

Last year (July 2022), we moved the Debian and RPM repositories from `downloads.apache.org` to Apache's JFrog Artifactory server ([CASSANDRA-17748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17748)).

If you have a look at the official [Apache Cassandra Download](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) page, there is a message that warns you about it:

> ⚠️ Debian and RedHat package repositories have moved!
>
> Debian’s `sources.list` and RedHat’s `cassandra.repo` files must be updated to point to the new repository URLs (see below).

We also announced the change in [Changelog #18](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-18-August-2022.html) and [Changelog #19](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-19-September-2022.html).

The new repository URLs are:

- Debian - `https://debian.cassandra.apache.org`
- RPM - `https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org`

Specifically for C* 3.11.13:

```
$ curl -L https://debian.cassandra.apache.org/pool/main/c/cassandra/ \
  | grep cassandra_3.11.13_all.deb
<a href="cassandra_3.11.13_all.deb">cassandra_3.11.13_all.deb</a>  14-May-2022 00:15  29.26 MB
```

Please make sure you update your configuration to use the new sources. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it we need to use archive instead of www so that it gets the deb file from the archive

echo "deb http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).